# QT program's display gets frozen and scrambled

Tags: qt, background, freeze

I haven't found anyone who's stated a problem similar to this, but then again maybe it's because I don't know the right term for the graphical glitch I'm having. This program worked and displayed just fine a week ago, but now it doesn't. I (or rather, "we," since it's a school project) haven't made any changes to it since then. It's made with QT, and running on CentOS. Here's a screenshot:

[Screenshot of QT glitch](http://img27.imageshack.us/i/screenshot6ck.png/)

Whatever is behind the window shows in the background, and whatever happens in the window gets frozen on screen. For example, if a word is supposed to flash on the screen and then disappear and be replaced by another word, the first word does not disappear. Instead, the second word just appears on top of it.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction as to what could be doing this? I could post a code snippet, if I knew what part to post a snippet of. :S

Answer (score 0):

Is the UI just one giant QGraphicsScene object?  If so then it could well be an OpenGL driver issue.  If not, then I'm going to guess that it's the underlying Qt painting system that has become corrupted, and just reinstalling Qt should do it.